# How to extract elements from loaded files with Time extension?

Tags: netlogo

With the time extension, I loaded time series :

```
let ts time:ts-load "File.csv"

{{time:LogoTimeSeries TIMESTAMP,Date-2
2010-08-01 05:37:00.000,2010-08-01 18:21
2010-08-02 05:39:00.000,2010-08-02 18:19
2010-08-03 05:40:00.000,2010-08-03 18:18
2010-08-04 05:41:00.000,2010-08-04 18:17
```

How can I extract each element of the first column ts[i,1] and the second column ts[i,2] in "ts" to use the following code :

```
set start-date time:create "2013/01/01 00:00"
for i = 2 : length(ts) [
ifelse time:is-between start-date ts[i,1] ts[i,2]  [....] [....]
set start-date time:plus start-date 1.0 "minutes" ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think one way at least would be to turn the time series into a list of lists using

```
set tslist time:get-range ts time:create 2000-01-01 time:create 2050-01-01 "all"
```

where the first and second dates in the range are earlier and later, respetively, than any TIMESTAMP in your time series, since that will then return all the values.  (I guess the second date could just be any date equal to or later to the second TIMESTAMP in the series since you only want the first two.)

Then you can refer to ts[1, 1] as "item 0 item 0 tslist", ts[1,2] as "item 1 item 0 tslist", and so on. I'm assuming that the indices in your pseudo code are starting at one, not zero.)